# Discord.py check define message.content

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to check when I use the command, which object I sent e.g. user/member, channel, role

```py
@foo.command()
async def define(ctx, arg) #the arg as id, mention or name
   if arg == discord.Role:
     await ctx.send("its a role")
   elif == discord.Channel:
     await ctx.send("its an channel")
    # more checks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done. Have a look at:

```
import typing #module you need
...
arg: typing.Union[discord.Member, discord.User, discord.Role, discord.Channel, int] = None) #arg itself
    ...
    if arg is None: #checking if arg is none
        ...
    elif isinstance(arg, int): #chechking if arg is int
        try:
            arg = ctx.guild.get_channel(channel) or (await ctx.guild.fetch_channel(channel)) #checking if bot can get/fetch channel by its id
        except Exception:
            ...
            try:
            ... #if bot didn't manage to get/fetch channel, then you should try with roles, users etc
        ...
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadUnionArgument): #error handler
        ...
```

:D

Comment: Thanks and how can i use it in a bot.wait_for function?

Comment: what do you mean?